# Moving Windows 7 user library (desktop, my docs...etc) to another location

Tags: windows, vbscript, special-folders

In Windows 7, I cut the user library folders and then I paste them to another location (including the content of them). When I do it that way, Windows 7 makes the changes needed (registry, path ... etc.) in order to get those special folders working again.
Is there a way to script it (in VBS if possible)?

I've given a look at WshShell.SpecialFolders commands and the fso.MoveFolder but I don't find the way...

Does anyone have an idea or a link in order to help me? Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use shell objects from Shell32. This lists or executes a command on a file/folder object (eg Cut). You can use Shell.namespace to get a special folder, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774094(v=vs.85).aspx

```
HelpMsg = vbcrlf & "  ShVerb" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  David Candy 2014" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Lists or runs an explorer verb (right click menu) on a file or folder" & vbcrlf  & vbcrlf & "    ShVerb <filename> [verb]" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "  Used without a verb it lists the verbs available for the file or folder" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The program lists most verbs but only ones above the first separator" & vbcrlf & "  of the menu work when used this way" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf 
HelpMsg = HelpMsg & "  The Properties verb can be used. However the program has to keep running" & vbcrlf & "  to hold the properties dialog open. It keeps running by displaying" & vbcrlf & "  a message box." 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag = WScript.Arguments 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Ag.count = 0 then 
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - No file specified"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    Else If Ag.count = 1 then 
        If LCase(Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/")) = "/h" or Replace(Ag(0),"-", "/") = "/?" then 
            wscript.echo HelpMsg 
            wscript.quit
        End If
    ElseIf Ag.count > 2 then 
        wscript.echo vbcrlf & "  ShVerb - To many parameters" & vbcrlf & "  Use quotes around filenames and verbs containing spaces"  & vbcrlf
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    If fso.DriveExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
'       Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.self
        msgbox ag(0)
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    ElseIf fso.fileExists(Ag(0)) = True then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(fso.GetParentFolderName(Ag(0)))
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(fso.GetFileName(Ag(0)))
    Else
        wscript.echo "  ShVerb - " & Ag(0) & " not found"
        wscript.echo HelpMsg 
        wscript.quit
    End If

    Set objVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs

    'If only one argument list verbs for that item

    If Ag.count = 1 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If len(cmd) <> 0 then CmdList = CmdList & vbcrlf & replace(cmd.name, "&", "") 
        Next
        wscript.echo mid(CmdList, 2)

    'If two arguments do verbs for that item

    ElseIf Ag.count = 2 then
        For Each cmd in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If lcase(replace(cmd, "&", "")) = LCase(Ag(1)) then 
                wscript.echo(Cmd.doit)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    'Properties is special cased. Script has to stay running for Properties dialog to show.
        If Lcase(Ag(1)) = "properties" then
            WSHShell.AppActivate(ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties")
            msgbox "This message box has to stay open to keep the " & ObjFolderItem.Name & " Properties dialog open."
        End If  
    End If
End If
```

Copying files in a folder to a blank or existing zip file. Cause zip files are folders in the shell.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(1))
Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=SrcFldr.Items
DestFldr.CopyHere FldrItems, &H214
Msgbox "Finished"
```

Comment: Many thanks for : your time, your answer/hint and for helping each other !
I tried to transform the script you provided to me and to integrate it in my existing script but I'm stuck.
I think I'll have to call the script that way :
`arrFolders = Array("\Desktop\" [...] "\Downloads\")
TargetCommand = targetPdir & " Coller"
For Each myFolder in arrFolders
SourceFolder = fso.buildpath(sourcePdir, myFolder) 
CutLauncher = "shverb.vbs "  & SourceFolder & "Couper"
sh.Run CutLauncher, 1, false
PasteLauncher = "shverb.vbs "  & TargetCommand
sh.Run PasteLauncher, 1, true
Next`
If you have a better idea?

Comment: And in fact, it seems to not work accross different partitions... Ouch!

Comment: My script shows technique. So something like set your folder with shell.namespace, then use the technique to get parent folder and your folder as a folderitem. Then MOVE it. Move updates the registry (copy copies the files). Move is same as cut and paste. I'll edit my post with a simpler example.